# Best way to achieve custom ui layout in Visual Studio (c#)

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, visual-studio

I have a simple layout [image]

What would the best way to achieve this? using WPF or Win forms with a custom list view?

Comment: depends 100% on the skill set that is in the team writing the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use WPF with [Styles and Templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683(v=vs.100).aspx).

Please notice there is a difference between ControlTemplates and DataTemplates, even though you can sometimes use either one for a given goal, only in slightly different ways.

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier for you to use WPF to mimic this. As you can style almost anything. While in WinForm you would have to handle the drawing yourself.